# I don’t understand how to write a Dockerfile to run Java HTTP

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, dockerfile-maven-plugin

I need to write a dockerfile that clones a repository from github and starts a simple Java server. Аm i moving in the right direction? please help

```
FROM alpine/git
WORKDIR /app
RUN git clone https://github.com/trekawek/jhttp.git 

FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=0 /app/jhttp /app 
RUN mvn install 

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=1 /app/target/jhttp-0.0.1.jar /app 
CMD ["java -jar jhttp-0.0.1.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are heading in the right direction in creating a Dockerfile that builds a Docker image. The image needs to contain all the dependencies your application requires, including Java itself.

I recommend reading Dockers official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) on Dockerfile:

1. [Create a Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-2-create-a-dockerfile)
2. [Dockerfile Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)
3. [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

The above links should provide enough information on creating a Dockerfile.

Comment: how would help, but no matter how)